# I can not run my migrated diaspora pod at all "bundle (LoadError)"

Tags: ruby, linux, deployment, server, diaspora

When I run the diaspora server by
    script/server
there are problems with
    web.pid

```
sidekiq1 load_external_pid_file: pid_file not found
```

crashed?

in the log "eye_processes_stderr.log" it is repeatedly written:

```
bin/bundle:3:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/lib/ruby/bin/bundle (LoadError)
from bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
```

I am using Gentoo.
I migrated that diaspora pod from debian 8

I tried downgrading:
(uninstalling newer ones before)

```
gem update --system 2.6.14
gem install bundler --version '1.16.2'
gem install rails -v '5.1.6.2'
```

I tried adding as much as possible PATHs for gem locations
and enhancing the PATH for bin files in Linux with much more directories

I expect that the diaspora runs successful.

Answer (score 0):

I notices on 'pid file not found' errors that the folder tmp/pids is missing. I then added the folder pods inside tmp.
Full path: diaspora/tmp/pids